# SQL Statement Select only when 1 State is used

Tags: sql

I have 3 columns

```
ProjektNummer, DokumentNummer, DokumentType
```

In `DokumentType` there are 3 possible values: Angebot, Rechnung, Lieferschein).

I want to select only those which have only `Angebot` and no other values.

Like you see in the picture, I only want the `ProjektNummer` (17011) where the `DokumentType = Angebot` and there no other entries for other values of `DokumentType`.

So it should NOT select `ProjektNummmer = 17016` because there are other entries with different values.

I hope you know what I mean.

I already tried if conditions and other stuff but I can't get it done.

Thanks for your help

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `NOT EXISTS` :

```
SELECT t.*
FROM table t
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 
                  FROM table t1 
                  WHERE t1.ProjektNummer = t.ProjektNummer AND 
                        t1.DokumentType <> t.DokumentType
                 )
    AND t.DokumentType = 'Angebot';
```

Comment: Maybe a stupid question, but why i have two different tabels ? (t,  t1)  The table name here would be t = t_doc and t1 = ?

Comment: @PhillipGruber. .  This will use same table in both `INNER/SUBQUERY`. Subquery filter out the different states  `ProjektNummer`s & `NOT EXISTS` will exclude those record from final result set.

Comment: Ah okay ty. But what is if i want do select for an other typ? why did the statement know for which type i am searching? Like 'Angebot' and Rechnung'.

Comment: The query will give the result the OP requires in the case of the sample data, because the required result is the only one with a single `DokumentType`. However, the required filter ("Angebot") should also be included, because if there are other projects with only a single DokumentType, and it wasn't "Angebot", they would also be returned.

Comment: Could you modifiy your answer pls with such an Filter ? I am not sure how i should do this. And thanks a much in advance

Comment: Thank you. Last question: for what is '<>' or how is it called so i can google it

Comment: @PhillipGruber. . `<>` is a NOT Equals to.

Comment: Thanks a lot for helping and explaining

Answer (score 0):

As I read the question, you only want `ProjektNummer`s that meet the criteria -- not the individual rows.  If so, then aggregation is a simple solution:

```
select ProjektNummer
from t
group by ProjektNummer
having min(DokumentType) = max(DokumentType) and
       min(DokumentType) = 'Angebot'
```